# PHPUnit is not installed on CentOS 7

Tags: centos7

I'm on CentOS 7 and I have installed PHP 7.2.33.
I'm trying to install PHPUnit using [this documentation](https://phpunit.de/getting-started/phpunit-8.html).

First two lines executed without any error

```
# wget -O phpunit https://phar.phpunit.de/phpunit-8.phar
--2020-09-30 06:56:30--  https://phar.phpunit.de/phpunit-8.phar
Resolving phar.phpunit.de (phar.phpunit.de)... 188.94.27.25
Connecting to phar.phpunit.de (phar.phpunit.de)|188.94.27.25|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 302 Moved Temporarily
Location: https://phar.phpunit.de/phpunit-8.5.8.phar [following]
--2020-09-30 06:56:31--  https://phar.phpunit.de/phpunit-8.5.8.phar
Reusing existing connection to phar.phpunit.de:443.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 2981560 (2.8M) [application/octet-stream]
Saving to: ‘phpunit’

100%[==================================================================================================================================================================>] 2,981,560   1.85MB/s   in 1.5s   

2020-09-30 06:56:33 (1.85 MB/s) - ‘phpunit’ saved [2981560/2981560]

# chmod +x phpunit
#
```

When tested for PHPUnit version, expected output wasn't there.

```
# ./phpunit --version
Content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8

#
```

Expected output for reference.

```
# ./phpunit --version
PHPUnit 8.0.0 by Sebastian Bergmann and contributors.
#
```

It looks like PHPUnit is not installed properly. What can be the reason?

Comment: It looks like you are running `php` and not `phpunit`.

Comment: @MichaelHampton: It is phpunit